# Rate of convergence of the eigenvalues of the samples covariance matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, covariance-matrix

Assume $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n$ to be i.i.d. normally distributed with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

What can we say about the convergence of the eigenvalues of the samples covariance matrix $\Sigma_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i x_i^t$ to the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$?

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517510/convergence-rate-of-sample-covariance-matrix) thread, but can we say something more when the data is normal? For example, to replace the $O_p$ notation to $\Theta_p$?